# How to make a bar chart with two colors for each bin?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with the names of articles, number of samples overall for each article, number of responders for a drug and number of non-responders. All together there are 9 articles:

```
Articles <- c("Nadeem Riaz", "David Braun","immotion150", "IMVIGOR210", "Alexander Lozano",
             "Van Allen", "Alexandra Pender", "David Lui", "Jae Cho")
Samples_number <- c(49, 311, 247, 298, 47, 39, 82, 121, 16)
With_Benefit <- c(26, 89, 168, 131, 27, 13,17,65, 5)
No_Benefit <- c(13, 102, 79, 167, 20, 26, 65, 56, 11)

MyData <- data.frame(Articles, Samples_number, With_Benefit, No_Benefit)
```

I need to make a bar chart with the Articles Names on the x axis, the overall samples number on the y axis, and color each bin so that for example responders would be blue and non-responders red, for each article.

I built a bar chart I just don't know what to type in the fill segment: (here I just typed the No_Benefit column but I know it's a wrong fill)

```
myplot <- ggplot(MyData, aes(x = Articles, y = Samples_number, fill= No_Benefit)) + theme_bw() + geom_col(position = "stack")
print(myplot)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the main problem is with the format of the dataframe; your data is in 'wide' format, but ggplot2 works a lot better with 'long' format. You can pivot your dataframe from 'wide' to 'long' with the [`pivot_longer()` function from the tidyr package](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html), e.g.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

Articles <- c("Nadeem Riaz", "David Braun","immotion150", "IMVIGOR210", "Alexander Lozano",
              "Van Allen", "Alexandra Pender", "David Lui", "Jae Cho")
Samples_number <- c(49, 311, 247, 298, 47, 39, 82, 121, 16)
With_Benefit <- c(26, 89, 168, 131, 27, 13,17,65, 5)
No_Benefit <- c(13, 102, 79, 167, 20, 26, 65, 56, 11)

MyData <- data.frame(Articles, Samples_number, With_Benefit, No_Benefit)

MyData_long <- pivot_longer(MyData, -c(Articles, Samples_number), names_to = "response")

ggplot(MyData_long, aes(x = Articles, y = Samples_number, fill= response)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_col(position = "stack")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much sir.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, you might want to double check you're not counting the same patients twice, e.g. Eli Van Allen and David Braun have coauthored a number of papers, so check that "Braun" (n=311) doesn't contain the "Van Allen" (n=39) patients.

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem is usually a data reshaping problem. [Reshape to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) and the plot a bar graph with `geom_col`.

```r
Articles <- c("Nadeem Riaz", "David Braun","immotion150", "IMVIGOR210", "Alexander Lozano",
              "Van Allen", "Alexandra Pender", "David Lui", "Jae Cho")
Samples_number <- c(49, 311, 247, 298, 47, 39, 82, 121, 16)
With_Benefit <- c(26, 89, 168, 131, 27, 13,17,65, 5)
No_Benefit <- c(13, 102, 79, 167, 20, 26, 65, 56, 11)

MyData <- data.frame(Articles, Samples_number, With_Benefit, No_Benefit)

library(ggplot2)

MyData |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(c(With_Benefit, No_Benefit)) |>
  ggplot(aes(Articles, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for the help